# I want the entry to be autocompleted in the PHP class

Tags: php, autocomplete, phpstorm, php-5.6

My PhpStorm PHP autocomplete works but I can't customize it for modded inputs.

This is my method in the PHP class:

```php
public function orientation($orientation = 'landscape')
{

}
```

First, I want this method to accept only the following values as input:

```
$orientation = 'landscape' , 'portrait' , 'square' , 'panoramic'
```

I want PhpStorm to suggest these values for input - that's the main problem.

Comment: Which php version are you using ? And what do you mean by "I want PHStorm to suggest these values for input"

Comment: Sure: either use special  `#[ExpectedValues()]` [PHP Attribute from JetBrains](https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-attributes?tab=readme-ov-file#expectedvalues) or `expectedArguments()` from the [Advanced Metadata functionality](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/ide-advanced-metadata.html#expected-arguments)

Comment: Version 5,6
What I mean is that PHP Storm should show me the values I mentioned above as autocomplete. @DylanKAS

Comment: It might be easier to turn `$orientation` into an Enum then, instead of always having to supply a `#[ExpectedValues()]` or `expectedArgument()`...

Comment: PHP 5.6... well that's not outdated at all. You won't be able to use enums then

Answer (score 1):

In PHP 5.6 I suggest to turn the argument type into a value object instead of plain strings. This is how it looks like:

```php
class Camera
{
    /** @param Orientation $orientation */
    public function orientation($orientation)
    {
        var_dump($orientation->getValue());
    }
}

class Service
{
    public function useCamera()
    {
        $camera = new Camera();
        $camera->orientation(
            Orientation::/* This is when your IDE kicks in with suggestions. */Landscape()
        );
    }
}

class Orientation
{
    private $orientation;

    /** @param string $value */
    private function __construct($value)
    {
        $this->orientation = $value;
    }

    /** @return string */
    public function getValue()
    {
        return $this->orientation;
    }

    public static function Landscape()
    {
        return new self('landscape');
    }

    public static function Portrait()
    {
        return new self('portrait');
    }

    public static function Square()
    {
        return new self('square');
    }

    public static function Panoramic()
    {
        return new self('panoramic');
    }
}
```

Note the private constructor and the factory functions taking care of proper initialization of the value object *$orientation*. This way you have an easy approach to narrow the available orientation options.

With later versions of PHP I suggest to use string backed enums instead. See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.enumerations.backed.php